# Remove SPECIAL stopwords for NLP

Tags: python, nlp, text-classification, stop-words

I am having a text classification task. I want to classify a set of documents in 4 categories (Business, Entertainment, Health, Technology). I create wordcloud for every category(i removed stopwords) and each wordcloud still contains stopwords such as (april, tuesday, yesterday, hundred). I merged the stopwords sets from SpaCy, NLTK, gensim in a complete set of stopwords. I performed a "remove_stopwords" function, but I realized that many special stopwords remain in the text.

**Question1**
I want to remove the following:

**Location Stopwords** – Country names, Cities names etc

**Time Stopwords** – Name of the months and days (january, february, monday, tuesday, today, tomorrow …) etc

**Numerals Stopwords** – Words describing numerical terms ( hundred, thousand, … etc)

Doing this by hand, its a time consuming task. Is there any better solution?

**Question2**

In another text classification problem with 4 classes(business, science, sports, world). Take a look for example at **worlds** column. Is it a good practice to use words like "monday, yesterday" to classify a text in "worlds" category?
[image]

Comment: What is the goal you trying to achieve here ? 
You know there is a country called king and a company called monday are you sure you want to remove them? Please describe the problem you trying to solve

Comment: @NaorTedgi I edited the question with a brief summary of the problem

Comment: Ok so I assume you got a sample of docs for each category , can you please show result of base line only using unigram and by gram without removing this stopwords? For a simple algorithm for example naive base

Answer (score 0):

In NLP there's no clear definition of "stop words", let alone "special" stop words. The concept usually refers to frequent words (typically grammatical words) which do not contribute to the semantic of the text, so they can be filtered out. Since there's no definition, one is free is define stop words in any way they want.

At the other end of the frequency spectrum, rare words can cause more serious issues because the classifier can mistakenly associate them with a class, even though they mostly happen by chance (this is overfitting). Rare words are not usually called "stop words", but most of the examples you mention probably fall into this category, like city names, months, numbers. In general rare words need to be filtered out in order to avoid overfitting, typically by specifying a minimum frequency (e.g. with argument `min_df` in [`CountVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)).

So in general the method is not to predefine a list containing all the possible "stop words": this would be costly, error-prone and it defeats the purpose of ML since most of the work of the classifier is done manually beforehand. The classifier can perfectly take care itself of words which appear frequently enough: if these words are not relevant for the class, it ignores them. However it could make errors due to rare words, so this should be taken care of... and this is much easier than preparing a huge list of stop words.